# Столкнулся с интересной проблемой в telebot с работой @bot.callback_query_handler

Tags: telebot

Есть простая программа, обработки нажатия lnlineKeyboardButton. При запуске программы кнопка видна, но при нажатии отказывается работать. Это очень странно, т к несколько месяцев назад все работало отлично! Telebot 4.15.3/ OS WIN 10 - 64. Я скопировал пару программ из интернета подобных, но там тоже полный отказ..

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('key')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    callback_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Press', callback_data='test')
    keyboard.add(callback_button)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Тестовое сообщение", reply_markup=keyboard)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def callback_inline(callback):
    print("Pressed")
    if callback.data == "test":
       bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, "Pressed")



bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: Проблема не воспроизводится, при нажатии кнопки Press бот отправляет сообщение Pressed, код рабочий. Telebot 4.14, Win 10. И ещё - в обработке коллбэка последней строкой желательно добавить `bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=callback.id)`, чтобы выслать сигнал о том, что колбэк был отработан.

Comment: У меня вообще не вызывается @bot.callback_query_handler. Т е чтобы я там не писал - это не выполняется. ООООчень странно, все работало месяцев шесть назад. Тут скопировал пример Aiogram, обычные кнопки - нет проблем, с inline - тоже самое.

Comment: Даже если просмотреть ответ через поле запроса в браузере https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXXXXXXXX/getUpdates?offset=-10 то все запросу отображаются в API, но при нажатии inline кнопки - там просто пусто. Т е вообще ничего не приходит. Хотя там в ответе должно быть какая кнопка нажата.

Comment: Пробовали запускать на других версиях библиотеки? У меня стоит чуть более старая, чем у вас. Хотя не думаю, что между ними были значительные изменения

Comment: Нашел причину, хотя полностью не понял причину всего этого. Создал нового бота и там все работает. Но вопрос в том, что я ТОЧНО НЕ МЕНЯЛ НИКАКИЕ настройки в старом боте. Да и какие там настройки отвечают за работу данных кнопок?